# Отправка формы по CTRL+ENTER или просто ENTER

Tags: forms, javascript

Подскажите, плиз, как написать `JavaScript` код, чтобы все абсолютно формы на странице отправлялись комбинацией клавиш, помимо нажатия кнопки мышкой.

Все, что мы имеем - это наличие тэга <form> на странице.

PS. CMS - InstantCMS

**Добавлено**

При нажатии вызывается функция:

```
function sendMessage(){

    var to_id    = $('select#to_id').val();
    var to_all   = $('input[name=massmail]:checked').length;
    var to_group = $('input[name=send_to_group]').val();

    if (to_id > 0 || to_all == 1){
        if (to_all==1 || to_group==1){ to_id = 1; }
        var action = '/users/'+to_id+'/sendmessage.html';
        $('form#newmessage').attr('action', action).trigger("submit");                      
    } else {
        $('input#gosend').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

}
```

Онкликом по сабмиту. Это где отправляется личны сообщения. Но на комментах эта функция не вызывается, но все равно страница перезагружается.

**Дополнено**

На самом деле проблема перезагрузки состояла в том, что атрибут action во всех формах пустой. То есть перед сабмитом ему нужно задать action-URL. В этом случае все работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form action="aaa.php" method="post"><textarea class="ctrlSubmit"></textarea></form>
<form action="bbb.php" method="get"><textarea class="ctrlSubmit"></textarea></form>
<script>
var t = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
var i = 0;while(t[i]){
    if(/ctrlSubmit/.test(t[i].className)){
        t[i].onkeyup = function(e){
            e = window.event || e;
            if(e.keyCode == 13 && e.ctrlKey){
                alert(this.value);
                //ну или this.form.submit();
            }
        }
    }
    ++i;
}
</script>
```

Скрипт работает без jQuery для всех textarea.ctrlSubmit .

**Добавлено**
Вариант, если известна только форма. Можно перевесить событие с document на все формы (или сделать им `onsubmit = function(){return false;}`).

```
<form action="aaa.php" method="post"><textarea></textarea><input type="text"></form>
<form action="bbb.php" method="get"><textarea></textarea></form>
<script>
function addEvent(elem, type, handler){
    if (elem.addEventListener){
        elem.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else {
        elem.attachEvent("on"+type, function() { handler.call(elem) });
    }
}
addEvent(document, 'keyup', function(e){
    e = window.event || e;
    var t = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if(t.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'input' || t.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'textarea'){ // если мы в инпуте или текстовом поле
        if(e.keyCode == 13 && e.ctrlKey){ // если нажато ctrl + enter
            if(t.form){ // если элемент в форме
                alert(t.value);
                //ну или t.form.submit();
                if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
                else e.returnValue = false;
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Здорово вы написали, универсально. Используя ваш код я упростил свой до трёх строк.

Comment: Однако я в условии написал, что кроме как наличие тэга &lt;form&gt; на странице мы ничего незнаем.

Comment: @ling спасибо за подробный и красивый код, но почему он просто перезагружает страницу, а не сабмитит форму? все варианты, что Ваш, что @Kremchik -a идентично работают, то есть просто перезагружают страницу.

Кстати, должно быть:

    t.form.submit();

Comment: Еще раз обновил.

Comment: Все равно страница тупо перезагружается((((

Chrome, Firefox, IE9, Safari - во всех такая фигня

**Добавлено**

Замечу, что этот код работает на стене, там как раз кнопка submit без атрибута name и id и &lt;form&gt; без атрибута id. Там где не работает, там присутствуют эти атрибуты.

Comment: Мягко говоря, это странно. Chrome, IE7, Safari - работает. FF глючит, но это решается сбросом onsubmit'а формы. Вы ничего больше, кроме этого скрипта, не подключаете?

Comment: Я же говорю, это CMS там 10-ка скриптов подключается, этот код прекрасно работает, если на отдельной странице (на пустой, где только одна форма без других скриптов).

Может иммитация клика по сабмиту поможет? А как скриптом на кнопку кликнуть?

    $("input[type=submit]").click();

не работает

Comment: Походу, у вас какой-то скрипт срабатывает раньше моего и перезагружает страницу. Проверьте еще раз, что у вас вешается.  
`$("input:submit").click();`, `$("input[type='submit']").click();` или `$("#myForm").submit();` - если отправить форму.

Answer (score 2):

Кроме `form` есть же ещё `textarea`? В чём текст набирается. Делаем ей `onKeyDown`.

```
<?php
    if ($_POST["demotextarea"]) {
        echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["demotextarea"]), "<br />\n";
    } else {
        echo "Введите что-нибудь:<br />\n";
    }
?>

<head>
    <script src="http://yandex.st/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>">
    <textarea name="demotextarea"></textarea>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("textarea").keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
            this.form.setAttribute("method", "post");
            this.form.submit();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Вариант без jQuery (изменил этот код после ответа **`ling`**, по-моему стало ещё проще):

```
<form action="/index.php" method="post">
    <textarea onkeydown="checkKey(event, this.form)"></textarea>
</form>

<script>
    function checkKey(e, form) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13)
            form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Ну, там нету `JQ`, но попробую подключить, хотя только ради этого не хотелось бы его подключать. Как быть без `JQ`?

Comment: Если конфликтов с другими инструментариями нет, то не подключать смысла нет. А так я дополнил ответ без jQuery.

Comment: JQ оказывается был подключен к странице (это CMS). Но почему-то форма не сабмититься, а просто перезагружается страница. Почему так?

вот мой код.

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("textarea").keydown(function(e){
 if(e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode == 0xA || e.keyCode == 0xD )){
  this.form.submit();
 }
    });
 
    });

Comment: Вы ожидаете POST? По умолчанию form может дать GET.

Comment: Я изменил первую часть ответа на полную страничку, она работает.

Comment: Ага, так же просто перезагружает. На оффсайте CMS говорят, что эту проблему не решили еще сами разработчики. Но может мы сможем решить? Возможные причины какие могут быть?

Comment: Эм. На чём сайт написан, PHP? Попробуйте для начала без jQuery, может из-за конфликта какого... Ну и конечно же на отдельной от CMS странице всё-таки код проверить.

Comment: Код на отдельной странице работает, проверил!!! CMS - instantCMS на PHP.

**Добавление**

Без JQ такая же ситуация. При нажатии просто кнопки submit (type=submit) сообщение отправляется нормально.